# Dropzone: determine why programmatically added file getting rejected

Tags: javascript, file, dropzone.js

I am attempting to programmatically add a File to dropzone.

In the dropzone init event hook:

```
zoneObject.emit("addedfile", image.file);
zoneObject.emit("thumbnail", image.file, image.url);
zoneObject.files.push(modifiedImage.file);
```

Which creates a dropzone object that looks like:

[image: dropzoneObject]

But when checking the dropzone's accepted and rejected files, it appears that the file I am trying to add is getting rejected:

[image: rejectedFiles]

I am trying to use dropzone's 'error' event hook to figure out why this rejection is occurring, but this event never gets triggered. Out of all of the [Dropzone Events](http://www.dropzonejs.com/#event-list) the only one that appears to be triggered in this programatic file upload is '*queuecomplete*'

**How do I determine what is causing this rejection?**

Answer (score 1):

Found a better way to upload an existing file to Dropzone programmatically:

Originally:

```
zoneObject.emit("addedfile", imageFile);                                
zoneObject.emit("thumbnail", imageFile, imageUrl);
zoneObject.files.push(file);
```

Referencing this [Dropzone Github Issue](https://github.com/enyo/dropzone/issues/418) I found an easier way to directly upload:

```
myDropzone.uploadFiles([imageFile])
```

Unfortunately there are no references to this *uploadFiles* method in the [Dropzone Documentation](http://www.dropzonejs.com/#events), so I figured I'd share some knowledge with all you Dropzone users.

Hope this helps someone